# rosjava installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Iam trying to install rosjava with following steps.

mkdir ~/my_workspace
cd ~/my_workspace
rosws init
rosws merge /opt/ros/groovy/.rosinstall
rosws set --git --version=groovy-devel rosjava_core 'git://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core.git'
rosws update
source setup.bash

Everything seems to be working fine until I run the rosws update command.It gives the error as following.

[rosjava_core] Updating /home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git fetch'
run at: '/home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core'
errcode: 128:
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
warning: http unexpectedly said: '0000'
[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : [rosjava_core] Update Failed of /home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core

ERROR in config: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : [rosjava_core] Update Failed of /home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63679/rosjava-installation/) by [Jhansi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4964/jhansi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-05-28**:
Are you installing for ROS groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

First do not use rosws, that was what I was told. Install from source and run catkin_make.

ROSjava has been  catkinized. Basically what I did to install was to download into my work space from source https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core

cd into my work_space and run "catkin_make". It then nicely compile everything for me. I did run into an error at one point but it has been resolved here https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/156

If catkin_make does not work, you can cd into ROSjava package and just run ./gradlew as well. Or at least I could about a month ago.

Hope that helps :D

---

Originally posted by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) with karma: 140 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-05-28**:
other potential bugs when it does start compiling for you, usually solved by setting JAVA_HOME, I ran into the same problem as this link and the second answer solved the issue for me

http://answers.ros.org/question/31800/building-rosjava-fails-at-task-apache_xmlrpc_commoncompilejava/

**Comment by [Jhansi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4964/jhansi/) on 2013-05-29**:
It gives the error as:     What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':rosjava_test:compile'.

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.8.2.